# Application of Sylow's theorem

Tags: group-theory

Let $p>q$ be primes.

$ (1):  \exists $ non-abelian group of order $pq$ $\Longleftrightarrow$ $p \equiv 1 (mod \ q)$

$(2):$ Any $2$ non-abelian groups of order $pq$ are isomorphic to each other.

Proof of claim $(1):$

Suppose $\exists$non-abelian $G$ of order $pq.$ Let $P$ be the $p-$sylow subgroup of $G$ and $N(P)$ be the normalizer of $P$ in $G.$ Then, $P \leq N(P) \leq G$ and so $P = N(P)$ or $P=G.$

If $P=N(P).$ Then, $|G:N(P)|= q = 1 + kp$ $(k > 0),$ by Sylow's theorem. This contradicts that $p>q.$ So $G = N(P)$ and $|G:N(P)|=1.$ How do I proceed to show $p \equiv 1 (mod \ q) ? $

Conversely, suppose $p  \not \equiv 1 (mod \ q).$ How do I proceed from here?

$(2):$ Could anyone advise on the proof ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $p > q$ and $P$ is a $p-$Sylow subgroup, $Q$ is the q-Sylow subgroup. You know that the p-Sylow subgroup $P$ is normal in $G$.

Now suppose $p\neq 1\pmod{q}$, then the number $n_q$ of q-Sylow subgroups must also be 1, and hence $Q\triangleleft G$.

Now check that $G = PQ$ and since $P\cap Q =\{e\}$, $G$ is abelian; and in fact
$$
G \cong P\times Q \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}
$$

Now if $p\equiv 1\pmod{q}$, then it is possible that $n_q = p$; and so $Q$ may not be normal in $G$. Also, there is a non-trivial homomorphism $\alpha : Q \to Aut(P) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$. This will give a non-trivial semi-direct product.

Furthermore, any two non-zero homomorphism $\alpha, \beta : Q\to Aut(P)$ will have the same image in $Aut(P)$ (since $Aut(P)$ is cyclic and so has a unique subgroup of order $q = |Q|$). Hence, the two corresponding semi-direct products will be isomorphic.

Comment: Isomorphic images is not enough. But fortunately, the images are in fact identical and the morphisms are injective.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft : Thanks, edited to correct that error.

Comment: This is what i have written but then I was afraid OP may not be familiar with direct product criterion... I got up to the stage that it has unique sylow p and sylow q subgroups but then I am wondering if there is any other approach... please help me to see if there is any other way..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik : I don't think there is any other way to do this - this example ($p \equiv 1\pmod{q}$), is almost the poster-boy for semi-direct products!

Comment: oh.. ok ok.. Thank You :)