# Let $p>q$ be primes such that $p \equiv 1 \pmod q$. Then there exists exactly one (up to isomorphism) abelian group of order $pq.$

Tags: group-theory

Let $p>q$ be primes such that $p \equiv 1 \pmod q$. Could anyone advise me on how to show there exists exactly one (up to isomorphism) abelian group of order $pq$? Thank you.

Comment: Do you already know the structure theorem for finite abelian groups?

Comment: Hint : show that any such group is isomorphic to $C_p\times C_q$ where $C_n$ is shorthand for the cyclic group of order $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If $|G| = pq$ is abelian, let $H$ and $K$ denote the p-Sylow and q-Sylow subgroup respectively. Since $G$ is abelian, $H, K \triangleleft G$. Check that :

a) $H\cap K = \{e\}$ and hence $G = HK$

b) $aba^{-1}b^{-1} = e$ for any $a\in H, b\in K$

c) $H \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, $K \cong \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$

d) Conclude that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z}$.

e) Since $p\neq q$, conclude that $G \cong \mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you for advice. May I know how you establish the existence of  such $G$ and how does (e) imply that there exists exactly one(up to isomorphism) of such $G?$

Comment: Because any such group is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/pq\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Thank you! Pardon my ignorance, how do we establish the existence of that abelian $G$ of order $pq?$

Comment: I just answered this today : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/570198/application-of-sylows-theorem

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your answer (in my previous post) made use of $p \not \equiv 1 (mod \ q)$ but in this case, we have $p \equiv 1 (mod \ q).$